# Get and render image from API in (Vue)JS?

Tags: image, vue.js, express, http, axios

I have a website running VueJS at `localhost:3000` which does some stuff to call `this.nextImage()`.

```
methods:
// content //
async nextImage() {
    console.log("In nextImage from App.vue"); // keeping track of location

    try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5050/images');
        
        console.log(response.data);

        [how to make an image?]
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
// content //
<template>
    <!-- stuff -->
    <div class="picture"><img :src="[what should go here?]" :alt="imageName"></div>
    <!-- more stuff -->
<template
```

on `localhost:5050` is an express server, which includes this:

```
const path = require('path')
// content //
app.get('/images', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Express server: /images"); // tracking location

    let imageName = 'myImage'
    let imagePath = path.join(__dirname, '/images/' + imageName + '.jpeg')

    res.sendFile(imagePath)
})
```

Logging the response.data gives

```
����JFIF���
!.%+!&8&+/1555$;@;4?.4514+$+44444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444���"����B   !1AQ2aq���"BR�����b�#3CSr���D��$%4����&1Q!Aa�2q�"��?�Z�UyEZL�>��ˀ��@�'G
��YU�U�$RlX�d<ǜ
(... abbreviated because I had too much code)
```

I need two pretty straightforward things:

1. The image to render properly
2. The name of the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a pretty easy fix. I didn't actually need to send the file itself, just a link to the file (just `app.send(imagePath)`). When the client makes a GET call to the server, they get a url that can just be included in the `img` tag like so: `<img source="imagePath">`.